# how to use the slice method to take a random element from an array and store it

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array lets say `array x = A,B,C,D,E`

I want to use the slice function to take a random element from my array and store it for later use in a new var

so I get a new variable i.e.  `var y= x.slice`

But I do not want to specify which element it takes from the array, I want it to be random each time how do I randomize the slice ?

Comment: Why use `slice` to get an element ?

Comment: `var y = y[~~(Math.random()*y.length)]`

Answer (score 11):

use `splice()` to extract and remove an element from an array.

Use `Math.random()` to generate a random number from 0 to 1

multiply by the number of elements or `length` of the array

and trucate with `Math.floor()` the result to get a random index into the array.

```
var x = ['a','b','c','d']; 
var y = x.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*x.length),1);
```

now, `y` contains the new array of the single element that has been extracted, and `x` contains the array of the remaining elements.

if instead of an array you just want the element returned, change that line to

```
var y = x.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*x.length),1)[0];
```